# Global variable inside the class and local function variable

Tags: c++

I tried out a c++ program, where i declared a variable of type int named "a" inside a class. And created a function named "b" inside which again i declared a variable named "a" and assigned the value to it.  The variable "a" inside the function is considered as local variable. And if i want to assign the value to the variable a which is present in the class definition(not inside the function), how can i do it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a{
    public:int a;//need to assign value for this "a" inside the function how can i do it
    int b(){
        int a=5;
        a=7;
        cout<<a;
    }
};
int main() {
    a A;
    A.b();
}
```

Comment: put `int & ra = a;` before you decare `a` in the function. Then use `ra` to refre to the class scope `a`.

Comment: You need an instance of the class. Then use that instance to scope the variable.

Comment: @RichardCritten Syntactically perhaps, but very bad code.

Comment: @nicomp why `ra` is local to the function?

Comment: This is purely academic, right? You don't actually want a member variable and a member function local variable with the same name, do you?

Comment: Hang on. You can't have a data member `a` in a class named `a`, can you?

Comment: @Beta yes it is academic.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes i tried this program.  It works when the name of the class and data members are same

Comment: You sent me checking, and it does indeed seem [valid](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#18). I learned something today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `this->a`.

`this` allows you to access the members and methods of an instance from within.

**EDIT:** this is an academical exercise, but a bad programming practice. Just use different names for classes, members and variables.

Comment: ... even if they are hidden by something in the member functions scope.

Answer (score 8):

To access the class variable you can use `this` keyword .
For more explanation and getting knowledge of 'this` keyword you can go [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a{
    public:int a;//need to assign value for this "a" inside the function how can i do it
    int b(){
        int a=5;
        a=7;
        this->a = 8; // set outer a =8
        cout<< "local variable a: " << a << endl;
        cout<< "class a object variable a: " << this->a << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
int main() {
    a A;
    A.b();
    cout << "A's variable a: " << A.a << endl; //should print 8
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the `class`-qualified name of `a`, i.e.: `a::a`, will do:

```
a::a=7;
```

Comment: That can't work. This will refer to the constructor.

Comment: Well, [this says](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.qual#2) it shouldn't. I'd check your compiler flags if I were you.

Comment: Well, that's distressing

Comment: Aha, so it is indeed correct. [The injected class name is hidden](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding#2). +1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is lying under the lack of `this` pointer to the class variable.

If you have a local variable inside your class function that is identical to the class variable, then you must use `this` keyword for the compiler to distinguish.

An easy mistake people tend to do is when having exactly the same names for the mutator's parameter variable as the class' variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    int numberA;
public:
    void setNumberA(int numberA) {
        numberA = numberA; /*Incorrect way, the compiler thinks 
                             you are trying to modify the parameter*/

        this->numberA = numberA; //Correct way
    }
};
```

In your case, you must use `this->a` inside the function `b()`.